# Looping over attributes in validation fails to stop set of attribute

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Normally in my backbone validation, I have a crazy amount of `if()` statements, as I've seen in many other code samples as well. Validation is pretty much a crap shoot in backbone; however, the `if()` way seems to work. I want to clean up the code a bit and wrote some code that does `return error` which should stop backbone from saving the attribute, but it doesn't!

## OLD Code that works

```
validate : function(attr){
    if(attr.firstName){
        var defaultValue = 'first name',
            value = attr.firstName.toLowerCase();

        if(value == defaultValue){
            return 'error';
        }
    }
}
```

## NEW code that doesn't work

```
//My default strings from another place
MyApp.strings.defaults = {
    firstName : 'first name'
}

//Model Validate function
validate : function(attr){
    jQuery.each(attr, function(key, value){
        var defaultValue = MyApp.strings.defaults[key];

        if(defaultValue){
            defaultValue = jQuery.trim(defaultValue.toLowerCase());

            if(value == defaultValue){
                console.log(value, defaultValue); //fires, and outputs both as being the same
                return 'error';
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Are you not allowed to loop over the attributes in Backbone validation?

Answer (score 2):

You are not returning any value from the validate method, you were returning `'error'` from the `each()` callback method, not from `validate`

```
//My default strings from another place
MyApp.strings.defaults = {
    firstName : 'first name'
}

//Model Validate function
validate : function(attr){
    var error;
    jQuery.each(attr, function(key, value){
        var defaultValue = MyApp.strings.defaults[key];

        if(defaultValue){
            defaultValue = jQuery.trim(defaultValue.toLowerCase());

            if(value.toLowerCase() == defaultValue){
                console.log(value, defaultValue); //fires, and outputs both as being the same
                error = 'error';
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
    return error;
}
```

Comment: Also I noticed that in the original function you call toLowerCase on the attribute itself (attr.firstName.toLowerCase()), but in the new function you call toLowerCase on the defaultValue (defaultValue.toLowerCase()). This may be intentional, but it feels like a subtle bug.

Comment: @Fuzzley thanks for pointing that out... looks like a bug to me too... made the correction

Comment: Thanks! That is exactly what it was! Also, thanks for pointing out the bug in my code about string comparisons.